# Uploading file to ASP.NET MVC using Java HttpClient

Tags: java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to upload any file from Java Console application to ASP.NET MVC web application.
For this, I am using Apache HttpClient library.

**ConsoleApplication.java**

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:52031/home/DataPost");
        File file = new File("A.txt");

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");
        mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);


        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();// Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            builder.append(line);
        } 
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

ASP.NET **HomeController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string DataPost(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        return file.FileName.ToString();
    }
```

I carefully debugged the above code and found out that java program properly accessing DataPost method, but could not upload the file as file parameter is null in the method.
I google about it and found some stackoverflow questions on java httpclient, but none of the questions are about server side implementation.
Please let me know, where I am doing wrong.
Thanks